# Documentation beta

Tags: discussion

I see that the [Documentation Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) is [now live](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/?cb=1).

Is this going to get pushed to DBA.se at any point, or is it going to only live on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 10):

How do people feel about doing this unofficially on main?

It wouldn't have the bells and whistles of the documentation site, but the 'multiple examples sorted by votes' format is not that different from the normal Q&A here.

We could tag all the topics [documentation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documentation) and have an agreed template for the questions, possibly including sections for syntax, remarks etc as well as the topic name.

There is some doubt in my mind whether or not we have enough active contributors here, but I also am very doubtful that SO will do as good a job of database documentation as they will for programming topics like c#.

Answer (score 6):

I am actually relieved that Documentation is ***not*** appended to dba.SE (yet). It was a major mistake to go live on SO, since it's largely incompatible with the main site. It has a broken reputation system and invites edit wars.

If they can resolve the issues, it might make sense for other sites, too. But certainly not in the immature state it is now. I would much rather have something [along the lines @Jack laid out](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2578/3684) in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the immediate and medium-term future, Documentation will be a Stack Overflow exclusive.

For the distant future (as in, multiple years down the line at the earliest), well... we don't have solid plans to expand it beyond SO, but it's early enough that anything is theoretically possible.

Comment: Seems like a poor decision, given the expertise on SE sites. Only my opinion, of course. I know many people that only answer on here, for example, as the general consensus is that the quality on SO in this domain is poorer.

Comment: @Phil Despite the higher quality and higher proportion of on-topic [DBA.se] SQL-related Q&As vs. those on [SO], there's nothing to say that the users here at [DBA.se] can't be the ones to be the editors in [SO]'s documentation section.